# How can I fix [entrypoint.sh: not found] in Docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Django project file and Docker in Ubuntu server.
And when I build docker image, it creates well.
But when I up this image, 'python: 1: ./AA/entrypoint.sh: not found' error occurred.

My `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM python:3.10.11

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -y update \
        && apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib \
                libpq-dev \
                gcc \
                python3-dev \
                musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./AA/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `entrypoint.sh` is

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
        echo "Wating for postgres..."

        while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
                sleep 0.1
        done

        echo "POSTGRESQL started"
fi

python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

And the structure of files is...

```
In /usr/src/app/server/AA/,
   -> Django projects by git clone
   -> Dockerfile
   -> docker-compose.yml
   -> entrypoint.sh
```

I tried these codes in `Dockerfile`, but all have same error.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./AA/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/usr/src/app/server/AA/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: You can run the slightly awkward `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls your-image ./AA` to run a temporary container running `ls ./AA` to see what's inside the container.  Is the script actually there, or is it in the current directory?  Is it possible the script has DOS line endings, and it's looking for an interpreter `/bin/sh\n` ending with a carriage return character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your directory structure, the file ends up as `./entrypoint.sh` in your image, so

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

should find it.

Make sure that the script is marked executable by adding

```
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

after your `COPY . .` line in the Dockerfile

If that doesn't help, it might be something in your docker-compose file that causes it. So adding that file to your question would help.